# Replacement for Objective-C "lazy-getter-as-dependency-injection" pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

Short of [Typhoon](http://www.typhoonframework.org), I was told the way to do (or at least simulate) dependency injection in Objective-C was with the lazy-getter pattern:

```
- (Foo)foo
{
    if (!_foo) {
        _foo = [Foo sharedInstance];
    }
    return _foo;
}
```

I always *detested* this, as you ended up with multiple instances of this seven-line chunk of boilerplate code polluting each view controller. You couldn't even hide it in a category since you can't define properties on a category.

Until Swift gets annotations and introspection features and I can write something like:

```
@injected foo: Foo!
```

... what patterns are people using in Swift to obtain a reference to shared model objects from multiple Storyboard-instantiated view controllers?

Comment: Yes, I know about associated objects and I know about macros. Both also offend my sense of aesthetics.

Comment: *With* Typhoon we use auto-wiring to inject a shared model object into storyboard created VCs. Generally these have 'weak singleton' scope: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Autowiring-%28Objective-C%29 . . . As for lazy getters, disagree that they're a replacement for DI (with or without a framework).

Comment: Do you need to mark Swift components as @objc in order to get the reflection required for the auto-wiring working? Agreed re: lazy getters, *I* don't think they're much of a replacement for proper DI either, but the voluminous replies to this post (!) are evidence of the lack of other options people propose...

Comment: Rather than mark with '@objc' we extend NSObject. There are other quirks and eccentricities too, unfortunately - a bit like using KVO with Swift.